# Input type "color"?

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, colors

I checked out some input type from HTML5 and I found out that the chrome support for the input type color doesn't work. My chrome version is 15.0.874.121 and the [w3schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp) says that it's supported since the version 12 :

My question is just : why that doesn't work for me? Is it a regression of the HTML5 support in Chrome?

Comment: @Leon: they’re not talking about the standard in this case though — they have a table, headlined “Browser Support”, claiming that Chrome 12 supports `<input type="color">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve got standalone versions of Chrome for testing (see http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php), and neither Chrome 12, 13 or 15 seem to support `<input type="color">` — they all just show a text field. (As opposed to Opera 11, which shows a colour picker.)

The Reddit article linked to in [@WebDeveloper’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8339827/20578) says that html5test.com reports Chrome 12 as supporting field validation on `<input type="color">`. This is true — html5test.com does report that for Chrome 12 (and doesn’t for Chrome 15), but I’m not sure what that actually means.

Comment: it means chrome has removed the support either due to bugs. See chrome supported validation in 6.0 but Validation support in 7.0(to 9) was disabled and re-enabled in 10.0

Comment: Ah yes — what I’m not sure about is what support of validation means in this case. Did it allow us to check that the value of the field was actually a colour? If so, how?

Comment: i am referring to html5 validation

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I’m saying how did Chrome 12 validate that the contents of the field was a colour if it just rendered the field as a text field? What values counted as a colour? (And now that I’ve actually bothered to look at the HTML5 spec, I guess it checked that the field’s value was a [valid simple colour](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-simple-color).)

Comment: it's now supported in chrome 23

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I'm pretty sure that Google removed support for field sanitation because libraries like Modernizr used sanitation as a marker for support of the field type (and Google didn't really support the field type).  See http://modernizr.com/docs/ for more information.

Answer (score 9):

w3school is not a official doc. It has lot of errors. It's partially right though in this case. Just see this site http://w3fools.com/

As far as input type color is supported check this

**Following browsers now supports color widget**

Firefox 29

[image: Firefox 29 color input Ubuntu]

Opera Desktop 11

[image: Opera desktop color input]

Chrome Desktop 20:

[image: chrome input type color Ubuntu]

Android 4.4 / Chrome Mobile :

[image: chrome mobile color input]

Opera mobile:

[image: opera mobile color input]

Blackberry:

[image: blackberry color input]

Firefox os 1.3

Firefox os now supports color input but i still don't have a screen shot

This link/info is now old

http://www.reddit.com/r/browsers/comments/is1q9/does_chrome_safari_and_firefox_support_input/

```
Chrome 12: partial (minimal element support: yes, custom ui: no, value sanitization: no, field validation: yes)     
Safari 5.0.1: partial(minimal element support: yes, custom ui: no, value sanitization: no,field validation: yes)     
Opera 11.50: partial (minimal element support: yes, custom ui: yes, value sanitization: yes, field validation: no)    
IE 9: No
Firefox 5: No
```

If u want u can use this http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="color" />` is currently in development and is not yet implemented.

See:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83865

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82635