# html5 getting a color selector

Tags: html, forms, colors

I'm trying to make a form that lets the user chose their favorite color, then submit it along with the rest of my form. However this code snippet doesn't seem to work.

```
       <html>
       <body>

       <form action="http://httpbin.org/post">
            Favorite Color <input type="color" name = "color" value = "#ff0000" required/>
        </form>

       </body>
       </html>
```

When I run that, (additional code for other form requests not posted), it shows me Favorite Color, with a text box instead of the desired output, a colored rectangle.

The internet told me that color type isn't supported anymore on most browsers, but that seems silly to me. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color ([Polyfill](https://github.com/jonstipe/color-polyfill))

Comment: Thanks, I was using one of the browsers that doesn't support. thanks

Comment: Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338378/input-type-color