# Open a color input with display:none via a label (webkit)

Tags: css, html, webkit, html-input

I want to hide an `input` element and trigger it with an associated `label`.

Usually that's not a problem. I can simply set `display:none` on the input [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/z1ta7ou0/1/)

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="upload" type="file" />
<label for="upload">Upload a file</label>
```

For some reason **in Chrome** (Firefox works), this technique is not working for a **color input** - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/z1ta7ou0/2/)

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="colorPick" type="color" />
<label for="colorPick">Pick a color</label>
```

Is this a webkit bug or is there a logical reason as to why this doesn't work?

Comment: Doesn't work in my Chrome (41.0.2272.17 beta-m (64-bit)...interesting...frankly, I'm surprised it shows in FF.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338378/input-type-color

Comment: dont know the reason but the workaround  http://jsfiddle.net/mdcpgohj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is a bug, for chrome(not really sure about other browsers). you can have a workaround for this specific situation:  http://jsfiddle.net/z1ta7ou0/4/

instead of using

```
input {
  display: none;
}
```

use

```
input {
   visibility :hidden;
    width:0px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

seems like there is only `display:none` which causes the problem(label not getting associated), otherwise works fine.

I have also opened an issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=452838&thanks=452838&ts=1422440310), you can track it