# Checkbox hack - Is there a drawback to hiding a checkbox off-screen via position: absolute?

Tags: css

This is the checkbox hack:
https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

My question is why "hide" the checkbox by positioning it off the page, as shown in the example on CSS Tricks:

```
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
```

Why not just do:

```
display: none;
```

The answer at [How does css checkbox hack work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950272/how-does-css-checkbox-hack-work/29950376#29950376) says:

> "Hiding the checkbox through `display:none` could cause buggy behavior on certain browsers. Just hiding it from view by a `position: absolute` is safer."

Which browsers? And are there any drawbacks with using absolute position to place an element off the page? To be more specific, are there any drawbacks with using absolute position to place an **input** off the page?

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191386/why-hiding-elements-using-position-absolute-and-left-30000px but not an exact duplicate?

Comment: display:none remove the element so probably the browser will no more consider it

Comment: it's a screen readers issue, [refer to this](https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/)

Comment: @ZohirSalak and what a screen reader will read on a checkbox?

Comment: The checkbox hack is delibereatly hiding the checkbox. The label needs to be clickable, not the checkbox. Screen readers don't need to 'see' the checkbox.

Comment: Heh, I have no idea what prompted me to mention the buggy behavior in my original answer. I don't remember what bugs or which browsers I meant. Chances are I still supported IE7 or something ridiculous like that back then.

Comment: and to answer your question, there is no drawback to use position:absolute to hide the input since it's the intended behavior at the end

Comment: @Stephan Muller and Temani Afif thank you. That does answer my question

Comment: @TemaniAfif Please don't answer in the comments. Post an answer, instead

Comment: @TylerH it's not a *complete* answer as I didn't answer the other question and I don't have any official proof to say that it's fine to hide using position:absolute ... for me there is no drawback but probably someone will say the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

There is no drawback to using absolute positioning. It just depends on what kind of space you are expecting that element to occupy. Absolute positioning is a good answer because it means the element is not effecting the layout of the page and the element remains in the DOM. "Visibility: hidden" or "opacity: 0" will also suffice. However, they will still take up space on the page. This is fine in the event that you are just going to absolutely position something over the top anyway. Display none prevents the element from reaching the DOM and thus the functionality will not be available.